# Secure webapi in APIm?

Tags: azure-api-management

To borrow some thought on using APIm to secure webapi, are the scenarios below supported?

- certificate
  The intention is to secure the azure hosted webapi, my thought now is to have APIm to validate incoming calling client and check the thumbprint to be one of the certificate I configured in APIm, upon authenticated then APIm to forward the call to my webapi however using another certificate (where I am to hardcode the certificate in my webapi logic check)
- IP restriction
  The intention is to limit the caller IP in APIm, furthermore I can somehow configure webapi to accept the call only from APIm nowhere else (lock down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all the scenarios are possible. Refer below links

- [Secure Apis with client certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients)
- [Secure your backend with mutual certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates)
- [Restrict caller IPs policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs)